# installing Apache Archiva as Web Application on TOMCAT 7

Tags: apache, tomcat, installation, archiva

I installed `Apache Archiva` as a `Web-Application` on `Tomcat 7` ( [howto](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.3.5/adminguide/webapp.html) ). But i get following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'registry#commons-configuration' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'appserver.base'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:268)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:362)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1636)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


The troubleshooting of archiva and tomcat does not help and I do not understand the error above. Has anyone ever had this error? What does it mean and how can I solve the problem?
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4/adminguide/webapp.html 
Especially the line
`export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dappserver.home=$CATALINA_HOME -Dappserver.base=$CATALINA_HOME"`
HTH

Comment: i defined the environment variable CATALINA_OPTS with "-Dappserver.home=$CATALINA_HOME -Dappserver.base=$CATALINA_HOME" but i have still the problem

Answer (score 1):

On Debian tomcat7 package unpack to several dirs:

```
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7
CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat7
```

If you look into `catalina.sh`, you will see import of `setenv.sh`.

**Right way** is define this system properties into `/var/lib/tomcat7/setenv.sh`, 
like this:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dappserver.home=$CATALINA_HOME -Dappserver.base=$CATALINA_HOME"
```